# Prove that $P(X)=P(Y)\oplus P(X\setminus Y)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $X$ be any set and consider the ring $(P(X),\triangle,\cap)$, where $P(X)$ denotes the power set of $X$. Further let $Y\subseteq X.$ It is required to prove that $P(X)=P(Y)\oplus P(X\setminus Y)$. Here $\oplus$ denotes the internal direct sum.

I could show that $P(Y)$ and $P(X\setminus Y)$ are ideals of $P(X)$. I should next prove that $$P(X)=P(Y)+P(X\setminus Y).$$ For this I tried showing that for any $A\subseteq X$ there exist $U\subseteq Y$ and $V\subseteq X\setminus Y$ such that $A=U\triangle V$. My idea was to consider the equality $A=(A\cap Y)\cup(A\cap (X\setminus Y))$. However I could go nowhere with this idea. Could someone please help me with some hints? Thanks.

Comment: Well, that is exactly the right idea, leading in a straight line to the answer. Not sure how else to help you unless you explain why you couldn't get anywhere with it. Is it because you don't understand what a direct sum is?

Comment: I cannot see the candidates for $U$ and $V$.

Comment: ... your candidates are $U=A\cap Y$ and $V=A\cap(X\setminus Y)$, just as you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $A\in P(X)$, $A=(A\cap Y)\cup(A\cap (X\setminus Y))=(A\cap Y)\triangle(A\cap (X\setminus Y))$, so $P(Y)+P(X\setminus Y)=P(X)$. Here the notation is a little weird with the $+$, headed for the $\oplus$ notation you need in the end. To be totally consistent, perhaps we should also use a $\triangle$ here and then a circle with inscribed triangle for the direct sum!  Or just use $+$ and $\oplus$ everywhere. Whatever.

Secondly, if $B\in P(Y)$ and $B\in P(X\setminus Y)$, then $B\subseteq Y\cap(X\setminus Y)=\emptyset$, so $B=\emptyset$, which is the zero element of $P(X)$. So $P(Y)\cap P(X\setminus Y=\{0\}$.

Thus you've shown the sum is direct.